# How would one calculate binary statistics in perl?

Tags: perl, binary, statistics, counting

I am essentially seeking to do what a typical/good hex editor can do:

https://www.hhdsoftware.com/doc/hex-editor/statistics-statistics-tool-window.html

I wish to be able to count the occurrence of each byte and put it into a table so I can determine the % of say '00' compared to 'FF'.

I have managed to get entropy, and the other statistics such as mean, median and mode are kind of redundant once I have the above complete.

There is also an issue that the binary files I am compiling statistics on are quite large, 32mb+.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres another way to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw( time );

$/ = \1;

open my $file, '<', shift;
binmode $file;

my %seen;

my $start = time();
my $n;

while (<$file>) {
    $seen{$_} ++;
    $n++;
}
my $end = time();

for ( sort keys %seen ) {
    printf( "%s%s%.2f%s\n", uc( unpack( 'H*', $_ ) ), " seen $seen{$_} times - ", $seen{$_} / $n * 100, "%" );
}

printf( "took %.3f seconds!\n", $end - $start );
```

output:

```
...
...
F8 seen 46475 times - 0.28%
F9 seen 46611 times - 0.28%
FA seen 46703 times - 0.28%
FB seen 48902 times - 0.29%
FC seen 46829 times - 0.28%
FD seen 47707 times - 0.28%
FE seen 47276 times - 0.28%
FF seen 1752333 times - 10.44%
took 2.374 seconds!
```

This is (WSL in windows) perl 5.22.1 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 69 registered patches)

Same thing in C - https://github.com/james28909/count/blob/master/count.c

EDIT:

Actually here is another, BETTER, example given by BrowserUK at perlmonks - https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1159266 - It seems to run faster than both examples/answers given.

```
use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw[ time ];

my $start = time;

open I, '<:raw', $ARGV[ 0 ];

my @seen;

while( read( I, my $buf, 16384  ) ) {
    ++$seen[$_] for unpack 'C*', $buf;
}
printf "Took %f secs\n", time() - $start;
```

Comment: Ow, reading one byte at a time? At least the system reads 8 KiB at a time. My solution has it read much larger blocks for better speed.

Comment: `$n++` is also very wasteful. Much better just to sum the hash values after the loop.

Comment: It honestly wasnt meant to be a drop in solution. its just another way to do it. the $n was just a way to  help calculate percentages of each byte seen. you are right... filesize could easily be obtained other ways. i know what to do to change it, but in all honesty it was not meant to be a direct code replacement, just an example of another way to count bytes. thanks

Comment: original post edited. added an example from perlmonks, that i asked along time ago. just cross referencing.

Comment: The bottom snippet is better, but still has two issues. 1) `read 16384` is silly, since `read` reads in 4 KiB or 8KiB chunks depending on your version of Perl. Best to use `sysread` to perform a single call to the OS. `sysread` also has less overhead. 2) If a value doesn't occur in the file you get an undefined count instead of zero. So it's best to initialize the counts to zero first. /// After you make these two fixes, you get my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Util qw( sum );

use constant BLOCK_SIZE => 4*1024*1024;

open(my $fh, '<:raw', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my @counts = (0) x 256;
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread($fh, my $buf, BLOCK_SIZE);
   die($!) if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;

   ++$counts[$_] for unpack 'C*', $buf;
}

my $N = sum @counts;
```

Comment: I am kinda confused, I can only seem to get the total bytes?

Comment: While that's what `$N` contains, `@counts` contains the information you requested. `$counts[0x00]` contains the count of `00` bytes, `$counts[0x01]` contains the count of `01` bytes, ..., and `$counts[0xFF]` contains the count of `FF` bytes.

Comment: Ahhhhh sorry! Yes! I rushed ahead a bit. Works like a charm! Takes about 7 seconds to calculate. You're a life saver!